# How do you solve: $\log_{\cos(x)} \sin(x) + \log_{\sin(x)} \cos(x) \le 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, logarithms

I have the following inequation:
$$\log_{\cos(x)} \sin(x) + \log_{\sin(x)} \cos(x) \le 2$$
I know that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ will give values in the interval $[-1, 1 ]$ but in the base there can't be any numbers $x \lt 0$ and in the argument can only be $\Bbb R^+ \backslash \{ 0 \}$. This being inequation makes it even harder and still after a few hours I'm clueless

How can you solve this and how would you calculate this function domain?

Note: The inequation/function is indeed written down correctly with $\le$ and it's possible there are no solutions.

Comment: For $\log_ba$ to be defined, the base should be $b>0$ and $b\neq 1$ and $a>0$. So you want those $x$ such that $\sin x, \cos x \in (0,1)$. Note that $x$ itself can be negative. Also think about base change

Comment: Realize that $\log_ba=\frac{1}{\log_ab}.$

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\log_ab=\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$$

By, AM-GM, we get

$$\log_{\cos(x)} \sin(x) + \log_{\sin(x)} \cos(x) =\frac{\ln \sin x}{\ln \cos x}+\frac{\ln \cos x}{\ln\sin x}\ge 2$$

If the OP is written down correctly, then the inequality becomes equality, namely
$$\log_{\cos(x)} \sin(x) + \log_{\sin(x)} \cos(x) =\frac{\ln \sin x}{\ln \cos x}+\frac{\ln \cos x}{\ln\sin x}= 2$$

therefore,

$$\ln\sin x=\ln\cos x\Longrightarrow \ln\tan x=0\Longrightarrow \tan x=1$$

so the solution is

$$x=\frac\pi4+n\pi,~~~n\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: Exactly. According to given question only case becomes that the expression is < -2 since equality at -2 and 2 are not possible. And solving that, there comes no solution.

Comment: It's written down correctly, its really $\le$, so I take it there are no solutions? But why how can we get to it?

Comment: If the OP is written down correctly, then the inequality becomes equality, namely $$\ln\sin x=\ln\cos x$$ @Punxil

Comment: Well, the approach I used was that take one of the terms on LHS to be t so the other becomes 1/t . Now the expression t+ 1/t is greater than or equal to 2 when t>0 and less than or equal to -2 when t<0. Here =2 possible when cosx = sin x. Another case is when the expression is less than 2. ( t not equal to -1). So t<0. Solving for this you get cos x>1 ( or sinx>1, depending on which one of the terms you took as t). Earlier, I forgot to take into account the equality case as pointed out by MathFail.

Comment: +1 but this "clue-less" question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.